# Creating MSI Installer with dotNetFramework inside it

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment

I do have VS2008 installed in my computer. I have developed a small app. Now i am ready to deploy it to my client's machine.

Since my client don't have .NetFramework installed in his winXP, I want to build up a msi file with both .netframework i am building and my application.

I tried creating setup file but when i test the deploy, it started downloading framework file from internet. Since my internet connection is too slow. I find embeding .netframework is my good solution.

So how do i embed .NetFramework in my MSI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that.
What you can do is to also send him the .NET Framework downloaded from Microsoft's website, in another file.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your setup project properties

click on the prerequisites button a window with your default prerequisites shown select 
what the prerequisites you want apart.

then at the last

select second option from three options of the prerequisites window
the second option is **download prerequisites from the same location as my application**

Answer (score 0):

This is an InstallAware feature for years (it launched in 2004).

http://www.installaware.com/

Other installer technology vendors may have this for a long time too. It just never appears in any free solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make an Install package in VS2008 install the 3.5 Framework from the same location as your application you have to do a little more work. See this [MSDN Forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/14b127b1-1ee6-4a2d-a741-bae8e288ce70)
 and this [MSDN Document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm). See Section **2.3.1.1 Enable Samesite for the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 bootstrapper package** 
Which gives these instructions.

```
Update the Package Data 

Open the [Program Files]\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 folder or %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 on x64 operating systems 
Edit the Product.xml file in Notepad. 
Paste the following into the < PackageFiles > element: 
<PackageFile Name="TOOLS\clwireg.exe"/>
<PackageFile Name="TOOLS\clwireg_x64.exe"/>
<PackageFile Name="TOOLS\clwireg_ia64.exe"/> 
Find the element for < PackageFile Name="dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-x86-en-US.exe" and change the PublicKey value to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
Find the element for < PackageFile Name="dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-amd64-en-US.exe" and change the PublicKey value to the same as in step 4 above 
Save the product.xml file 


Download and Extract the Core Installation Files 

Navigate to the following URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=118080 
Download the dotNetFx35.exe file to your local disk. 
Open a Command Prompt window and change to the directory to which you downloaded dotNetFx35.exe. 
At the command prompt, type: 
dotNetFx35.exe /x:. 
This will extract the Framework files to a folder named “WCU” in the current directory. 
Copy the contents of the WCU\dotNetFramework folder and paste them in the %Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 folder (%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35SP1 on x64 operating systems). Note: Do not copy the WCU\dotNetFramework folder itself. There should be 5 folders under the WCU folder, and each of these should now appear in the DotNetFx35SP1 folder. The folder structure should resemble the following:
o DotNetFx35SP1 (folder) 
    dotNetFX20 (folder 
    dotNetFX30 (folder) 
    dotNetFX35 (folder) 
    dotNetMSP (folder) 
    TOOLS folder) 
    en (or some other localized folder) 
    dotNetFx35setup.exe (file)
```

Answer (score -1):

There has been talk of a .Net framework bootstrapper for WiX for *years*. As far as I know, nothing's come of it, and from the blog posts it looks like the WiX project is struggling for developer resource as is. So keep an eye out, but don't expect anything soon.